# Come tradurre: committee?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, translation

Come posso tradurre in italiano **Committee**?

Nello specifico **Event Committee**?

Loro sarebbero i proprietari e responsabili di un evento (non sono per forza gli organizzatori).

Posso tradurre come **comitato**? Come parola mi ricorda un po' Magalli. Si usa dire il comitato di un evento?

Oppure meglio usare **commissione**?

Grazie!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direi che andrebbero bene sia ***comitato*** che ***commissione***, anche se commissione lo vedrei più legato a contesti come un'esame oppure un'inchiesta.

Si potrebbe anche usare l'**Organizzazione** di un evento, dove si intendono tutti i membri direttamente o indirettamente attivi nella preparazione/gestione di un determinato evento.

In alcuni casi particolari potrebbe essere anche tradotto come ***consiglio***, nel caso per esempio delle facoltà universitarie.

Comment: Ok grazie. Allora mi sa che lo traduco come comitato.